# Sending HTML via JSON from PHP to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I use jquery_form plugin to send html form to php. then php sends back JSON object.

Here is what PHP sends back

```
$content="<div>ABC</div>";
$json = json_encode(array("content" => $content));
...Here I also send $json to Mysql database...
echo $json;
```

Then I alert what comes back to Javascript.

Now in Mysql I receive `{"content":"<div>ABC</div>"}` which looks correct

But In Javascript alert looks like this `{"content":"<div>ABC&lt;\/div&gt;"}</div>`

Which makes problematic to jQuery.parseJSON to parse this object.

Please help me to deliver normal JSON to javascript.

**UPDATE**

I've tested php file in here http://codepad.viper-7.com/EBSM8G
putting there this code

```
<?php
   $content="<div>ABC</div>";
   $json = json_encode(array("content" => ".$content."));
   echo $json;
```

and the result is like this

```
{"content":".

ABC<\/div>."}
```

So what's the problem ???? I'm confused :(

**UPDATE 2**
Trying suggested hints changing one line to this

```
$json = json_encode(array("content" => $content,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

and the alert gives me this `{"content":"<div>ABC&lt;\/div&gt;","0":64}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

HTML

You won't see the opening div tag since it's getting parsed by your browser (it's there but you don't see it - check the source).
You do see the closing tag since (without additional flags) the slash is being escaped and it's not parsed as closing div tag.
Your browser will probably close the div tag right away thus giving you the line break (div's a block element).

JS

Javascript works perfectly fine
http://codepad.viper-7.com/inVZmv

Besides, you don't need to parse the string since it already is JSON when you use it within your JavaScript (except you put quotes around it). Consider the following example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SK5KaK

Comment: I think you're wrong cause alert shows starting div anyway. anyway I don't care about it I alert it just to get the result. Idea is to parse it with jQuery.parseJSON but there javascript fails with error. because there response data is problematic to jQuery.parseJSON.

Comment: I've checked your code and you are correct there javascript works perfect

Comment: dunno what your code looks like, maybe things get url_encoded

Comment: btw, you probably don't wanna have the slashes escaped - use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag

Comment: by the way in my javascript before alerting this data, I've put another alert >  alert('<div>TTT</div>'); and it alerts <div>TTT</div> just fine

Comment: Why do you wanna use jQuery.parseJSON anyway? The string you have already 'is' JSON when you use it.
http://codepad.viper-7.com/u2C1Zh
Of course you could output it as a string (by putting single quotes around it) but why would you do that?

Comment: Just to make it clear, you do not need to parse the string since it already IS JSON. Consider the following example, first parse will give null since it's an object, second will parse since it's a string.
http://codepad.viper-7.com/SK5KaK

Comment: well client receives 'responseimage' variable from server in which is JSON. So what should I put in alert then to alert 'content' variable???

Comment: Neither do I know what 'responseimage' variable is nor do I know what the actual purpose of your code is and why or what should be alerted - hence I can't tell. I'd appreciate an upvote though, haha

Comment: OK I explain. now look. javascript calls server 'Do some job!'. server php does something then puts some data   $content="<div>ABC</div>";   into $json = json_encode(array("content" => $content)); and echo it.    and this data come back to javascript client side as responseimage variable. I mean what server echoes, everything went into this variable. so here I need jQuery.parseJSON to make it JSON so I could access it with javascript

Comment: If I echo responseimage it is not object that's why I need jQuery.parseJSON to make it object first

Comment: Of course, when sending an ajax request you will have to parse the answer since it's a string. I can't reproduce your error. Can you provide a live example?

Comment: go to bestgeotours.com  , login using '1' , '1' as user/pass.  then press on '1' in upper menu. u'll appear on user page. there will be "add Photo" link. press it and choose some pic with min 480x360 size. and u'll get error

Comment: error will be JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: bestgeotours.com doesn't have no login (at least for me) ;)
If the error is "unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data" you know what's wrong. Probably a blank line after your last closing php tag (?>\n). Besides, if the error has changed you should probably start a new question.

Comment: do not use IE. bestgeotours.com there will be 2 input boxes on the upper part of page . put there '1','1' and press enter or button on the right.

Comment: here is my php end  echo $json;
 }
$db->close();
?>   so everything is ok here

Answer (score 1):

This might not help you now, but I would reconsider sending html via json, seems to me that such a simple div wrapper is unnecessary if you were to send a large chunk of page it will end up very messy.

I would either build the HTML directly on the page using the php on page reload, or if you are using ajax then just send the variables needed to build the content client side, this loosely coupled approach will be much more flexible

A more concrete example is tricky because your original post is quite abstract and concise, but if your form was name and age, I would send the json object like

```
{'name':'codemonkey', 'age':21}
```

and use JS to populate the HTML in jQuery that would be something like

```
$('.theName').val( jsonData.name )
```

Comment: I understand your approach, My task it to give user abbility to upload image and edit it. THis must be completed through several steps, and in each step after AJAX response I buld some dialog box with coplex HTML form with images buttons some script inside etc.  SO I thought sending complete HTML would be better. Cause I must do several diferent dialog boxes with HTML forms inside, you think better to construct them with jquery on client side ????

Comment: That'd be better. Especially when storing html in your database (as you seem to do it) it can get really messy when changing some of the code (since the data within your database won't get updated unless you do it manually)

Comment: html in database is just for testing with this problem. I don't need html in database.   But you think that building html form on client side is better then sending it through ajax from php ?

Comment: Yeah I sued to send complete HTML around and it does feel easier, but in the long run it causes problems if you ever try and reuse the code for anything else. If you are trying to upload images, have you looked at libraries like plupload ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use proper encoding within header() function.

Something like this:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/zZxzBd

Comment: In this case raw data looks like this 
 <pre> {"content":"&lt;div&gt;ABC&lt;\/div&gt;"}</pre>  
  and those <pre> make problems to jQuery.parseJSON 
and the firebug shows 
JSON.parse: unexpected character

Answer (score 0):

if you are sending just `$content` so why are you using array ?

try this

```
   $json = json_encode($content);
```